# How to use exp() in integration function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import exp, log, inf

def f(x):
    return log(log(x))/(x*log(x**2))

val, err = quad(f, exp(), exp(2))
val
```

I know the code is structured correctly but I cannot format the `exp()` correctly. What am I doing wrong? The function should output 0.069324. Thanks ahead of time for the help!!!

Here is the answer from WolfRamAlpha:

[image: equation and result]

Comment: To use the `exp` function to get `e`, use `exp(1)`.  That is, `val, err = quad(f, exp(1), exp(2))`

Comment: Using exp(1) outputs .12011 which is near double the true solution

Comment: It looks like the upper limit should be `2*exp(1)`, not `exp(2)`.  With `val, err = quad(f, exp(1), 2*exp(1))`, I get `val = 0.06932400271887294`.

Comment: Also, numpy includes the value of `e` as a predefined constant, `np.e`.  So you could also use `val, err = quad(f, np.e, 2*np.e)`.

Comment: Also, please indent and format your code properly. Thnx!

Comment: Thank you @Bazingaa and @WarrenWeckesser!

Answer (score 1):

numpy's exp is a function, not a number. You want

```
exp(1) = e
exp(2) = e**2
```

or maybe

```
import numpy as np
np.e
np.e**2
```

as your integration limits.

That said, I get

```
from numpy import exp, log

def f(x): 
    return log(log(x))/(x*log(x**2))

val, err = quad(f, exp(1), exp(2))
val
```

returning 0.12011325347955035

This is definitely the value of this integral. You can change variables to verify

```
val,err = quad(lambda x: log(x)/(2*x),1,2)
```

which gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `exp()` by `exp(1)` and you are good to go. By the way, once you have figured out the correct function, you can also use one liner lambda functions. Your code is perfectly fine. I thought of just sharing another possible way to implement the same thing.

```
f = lambda x: np.log(np.log(x))/(x*np.log(x**2))
val, err = quad(f, exp(1), 2*exp(1))
```

Comment: Using exp(1) outputs .12011 which is near double the true solution...checking my actual function now...

Comment: `exp(1)` is the correct way to do it. I am doubting the function

Comment: Agreed exp(1) is how you do it. The issue with my code was the upper limit where I put exp(2) instead of 2*exp(1). Ty!

Comment: Surprised to see this typographical error on Wolfram Alpha snapshot